# Error when trying to implement exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, exception

> error: declaration of 'virtual const char* numberOutOfBounds::what() const' has a different exception specifier

I have been searching around for a solution and I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong.

exceptions from my header file:

```
class FileException:public exception {
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};

class numberOutOfBounds:public exception {
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};
```

And the exceptions in my cpp file:

```
const char* FileException::what() const {
    return "Cannot open file";
}

const char* numberOutOfBounds::what() const {
    return "illegal number entered";
}
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing incorrectly here? 
I have looked around and can't figure out why I am getting the error message that I am getting.

Comment: There is already a `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: You have a `throw` specifier on your function declaration but not on the definition; add`throw` to the definition.

Comment: I took it off of the declaration and got a different error about how I was "overriding the virutal const char*" whatever that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `virtual const char* what() const throw();`

This function declaration has a `throw` declaration but it's missing from the definition.

You need:

```
const char* FileException::what() const throw() {
                                     // ^^^^^^^ - added
    return "Cannot open file";
}
```

FYI, there is already a `std::out_of_range` exception class.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to implement an exception:

```
class myexception: public exception {
virtual const char *what() const throw()
{
 return "Exception occured!!";
}
 }myexc;

int main () {
try
{
    throw myex;
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << '\n';
}
return 0;
}
```